# field name and help text disappear in multiple form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have multiple form that handle with one view.
When I want to show my form in `index.html` and specific the field,Such as `{{form_1.some_field}}` **All help texts and fields name disappear!**

When I use `{{ form_1}}` everything run correctly. **What is the problem?**

This is my files:

## index.html

```
<form method="post" class="mos-rtl">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <h4 class="mos-rtl">Section 1</h4>
        <p>{{ form_1.some_field }}</p>              
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 class="mos-rtl">Section 2</h4>
            {{ form_2.some_field }}
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## forms.py

```
class Form1(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Model1
            fields = '__all__'
class Form2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

## Views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_1 = Form1(request.POST)
        form_2 = Form2(request.POST)
        if form_1.is_valid() and form_2.is_valid():
            new_record_1 = form_1.save(commit=False)
            new_record_1.save()
            new_record_2 = form_2.save(commit=False)
            new_record_2.record_1 = new_record_1
            new_record_2.save()
            return redirect('administrator:view_admin_curriculum')

    else:
        form_1 = Form1(request.POST)
        form_2 = Form2(request.POST)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'form_1': form_1, 'form_2': form_2}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: what you mean dissapear exactly ? what is dissapeared ? labels ?

Comment: I mean that none of the `verbose_name` of my models show in the `index.html`. @gachdavit

Comment: `verbose_name` is rendered as a  html `label`. In your case, `{{ form_1.some_field.label }}` and verbose_name will be shown in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ form }}` calls `form.__str__()` method, which on the other hand calls `form.as_table()`. So, because of this `{{ form }}` and `{{ form.as_table }}` are rendered in a same fashion.

`Form` class also support different kinds of rendering methods, like `as_table()`, `as_p()`, `as_ul()` (This is how `Form` object should be rendered as a html). All these methods implementation are in `BaseForm` class, which represents parent class of `Form`. This is [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L272).

**So, You should try like this:**

```
<form method="post" class="mos-rtl">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <h4 class="mos-rtl">Section 1</h4>
        <p>{{ form_1.some_field }} {{ form_1.some_field.help_text }}</p>              
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 class="mos-rtl">Section 2</h4>
            {{ form_2.some_field }} {{ form_2.some_field.help_text }}
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you are trying to render `Form` fields manually like you did, You should render help_text (manually also), which represents attribute of field.

Comment: yes, it helps. Thanks! But do you know what is the reason? @gachdavit

Comment: Yes. {{ form }} calls `form.__str__()` method, which on the other hand calls `form.as_table()` {{ form.as_table }}. `Form` class also support different kinds of rendering methods, like `as_table()`, `as_p()`, `as_ul()` (This is just how `Form` object should be represented as a html). All these methods implementation are in `BaseForm` class, which represents parent class of `Form'. This is source code. [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L272]

Comment: Ahhaaa... I will add your comment to your answer. @gachdavit

Comment: @mostafarahnama I've answered you also about `verbose_name` in comments. Good luck !